# PIC24F debugger halts and resets upon I2C read of slave

Tags: i2c, debugging

I've been trying to debug my I2C communication between the PIC24FJ32GA002 and the PCA9546APWR bus switch for a couple of days now. I just want to test that I could enable a channel of the bus switch, so what I've done is write to the bus switch to enable a channel, and then read from the bus switch to confirm if the selected channel is enabled. I've had no problems writing to the bus switch using the debugger; however the debugger halts and resets all the time upon a read from the bus switch afterwards, although no breakpoint is set.

I've been trying a couple of ways to find out what is causing the halt, I've implemented exception handlers provided by Microchip: http://www.embeddedcodesource.com/codesnippet/address-error-trap  to see if hard traps such as address errors etc are causing this issue, but none of those handlers are entered when the debugger halts. The RCON and INTCON1 registers are zero as well.

So now I'm looking at the scope to trace the SDA signal line, somehow I couldn't capture the SCL line properly on the scope, but I assume it should be working if I see changes in the SDA line?

Here are a few pictures of the write sequence to the bus switch:
[image]

[image]

I think the sequence is right, from using the cursors, if **each bit is 40us long**, I get the correct write sequences and ACK from the slave. The switch address is 0xE0 for a write, and I'm enabling channel 2 of the switch. This is from pg 13 of the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9546a.pdf

Now, here is the picture of the read from the slave:

[image]

From where my time cursor is placed(ignoring the ACK period from slave), I can see that I'm getting the correct results from the slave which is 0x02, but somehow the debugger halts here all the time. I'm a little concerned about the SDA line not going high after the ACK from the slave though. Could that be the issue?

Here is my code for the bus read as well:

```
char I2C_bus_read(void){

char status;

I2C2CONbits.SEN = 1;
while(!IFS3bits.MI2C2IF);
IFS3bits.MI2C2IF = 0;
I2C2TRN = BUS_SWITCH_READ;
while(!IFS3bits.MI2C2IF);
IFS3bits.MI2C2IF= 0;
I2C2CONbits.RCEN = 1;
while(!I2C2STATbits.RBF);
status = I2C2RCV;
I2C2CONbits.ACKDT = 1;
I2C2CONbits.ACKEN = 1;
while(!IFS3bits.MI2C2IF);
IFS3bits.MI2C2IF = 0;
I2C2CONbits.PEN = 1;
while(!IFS3bits.MI2C2IF);
IFS3bits.MI2C2IF = 0; 
return status;}
```

EDIT: Following the comment below, my #pragma configuration bits have turned off the watchdog timer previously, and I'm running on the default 8 MHz clock. I2C is run at the standard 100 kHz.

I checked the RCON registers again, and I must have been confused prior, for RCON isn't zero as claimed, but the bits for power on reset (POR), brown out reset (BOR) and master clear reset(nMCLR) is set. What interests me the most is the (nMCLR) pin. Why is that pulled low? Could it be my hardware setup that is wrong? Attached now is my schematic for the I2C setup.

[image]

Comment: Check if you have a watchdog active.  Also the PIC has a register that indicates the reset cause on reboot, you can find a hint why your PIC resets in that register.

Comment: Are you debugging using a Microchip debugger?  Try running without the debugger - they introduce overhead and sometimes timing functions are affected.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Yes, I'm using a chipKIT programmer by Digilent. If running without the debugger, can I connect an LED and insert a statement after the read function to see if the code execution ever gets there? That's a way to test if it works, right? But I do need the debugger to read register values from the 3 light sensors to which the bus switch is connected.

Comment: On a sidenote: 1k pull-up resistors on the I2C bus is a bit small.  It is under the limit suggested by TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf .

Comment: That would be the approach I would use - some sort of bit-toggling to see if you get past the point where you fail with no debugger.  I often must use a UART port with an FTDIchip cable for debugging if I need to see values.

Comment: @le_top I see. So would changing the values to a 2.1k or so help? The reason I chose 1k was that the range of resistance was somewhere between 995 and 2.95k Ohm from pg 17 and 18 of the datasheet. Also, the MCLR pin is indeed pulled low. I think that's due to the SDA being pulled low for too long when sending out 0x02. So would having a higher capacitor value solve this?

Comment: @JohnBirckhead That's a great idea! I've already printed out the board though, unless I solder wires from the MCU to a breadboard to test

Comment: @LimLS 2k1 is definitively an acceptable value.

Comment: @LimLS From the datasheet " A Power-on Reset will clear all bits
except for the BOR and POR bits (RCON<1:0>) which
are set. " .  So you first have a POR and then the MCLR which goes high "late".  So IMHO the question is: why do you have a POR - check out your power line and your MCLR.

Comment: @le_top I have solved the problem last night. Indeed the reset was due to MCLR line pulled low during the I2C read. I'm guessing it's due to the switch pulling the SDA line low when sending out 0x02, which is the value of the channel enabled. Switching C8 from 10uF to 20uF did the trick. Not sure if it's the best solution though

Comment: For clarification, the 3.3V line to both the PIC and the bus switch is supplied by the debugger

Comment: @LimLS Ok, if the debugger is providing the power, then you basically lost power as suggested (on POR) and your MCLR is still low after POR.  I misread the schematic as I now see 10k pullups on the PIC SCL lines, but you have 1k on the switch buses.  The 1k pullup shown in the datasheet is for the test conditions (how TI tested the component).  Section 9.2.2 explains how to calculate the right operating resistor value for your design.  You're pulling 2x3mA=6mA on the supply by putting 1k resistors (3.3V/1k x 2).

Comment: @le_top You are multiplying by two to include both SDA and SCL lines? To be clear, my MCLR line is high after the POR, but it is pulled low during the I2C read operation from the bus switch, which causes the debugger to reset. And yes, I have used the equations in Section 9.2.2. The min value is (3.3-0.4)/3m ~967 and max value is (1000n)/(0.8473 x 400P) ~ 2.95k

Comment: So is the problem too much current draw which depletes the charge on the capacitor?

Comment: @limls Yes, I multiply by two because of SCL and SDA.  The debugger is limited with regards to the current it can provide.  So your voltage drops all of a sudden.  400pF is a lot, only compute such a worst case value if you really expect it.

Comment: @le_top Thanks! If I were to run this from a regulator powered by a battery source, would I have the same issue? I'm confused if the problem is with the current or voltage, or both. Isn't the cap supposed to maintain the voltage line? Also, what is a usual capacitance value? I don't know too much about that

Comment: The 10uF capacitor is there to cope with momentary local current surges, not to compensate for a weak powsource.  You should not have an issue if you power the circuit normally, not from the debugger.  If you do have an issue, there is a problem in the design.

Comment: can you confirm the basics? What are the open drain settings for the I2C pins ? are they set to digital and not analog? TRIS settings? etc.